# Example for an entire function of finite order but of infinite type

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently racking my brains for an example as described in the question.

I have an example

## $$e^{e^z}$$

which is of infinite order and infinite type.

Question is, does there exist an (entire) function of finite order BUT of infinite type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1/\Gamma(z)$ has order $1$ but infinite type.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function)

Comment: Many thanks! :)